# Combining 3 tables in one single select query in php

Tags: php, mysql

how do I combine these 3 tables in one single query in php? When I use this query I get the values from matches and sport as null. But when I change the last right join to left join the value of schedule becomes null. How can I fix this? Thanks.

PHP

```
<?php  
         $db_name = "atfest_db";  
         $mysql_user = "root";  
         $mysql_pass = "";  
         $server_name = "localhost";  
         $sql =  "SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name,start,end,venue FROM `sport` right JOIN `matches` ON `matches`.`s_id` = `sport`.`s_id` right JOIN `schedule` ON `schedule`.`m_id` = `matches`.`m_id`";
         $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 
         $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


         $response = array();


        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

        {
        array_push($response, array("teamone"=>$row[0], "teamtwo"=>$row[1], 
        "s_name"=>$row[2]));

        }

        echo json_encode (array("schedule_response"=>$response));




        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

Sport table is connected to matches b s_id while matches table is connected to schedule table by m_id.

**Matches Table**
[image]

**Schedule Table**
[image]

**Sport Table**
[image]

This is the output i get

```
{"schedule_response":[{"start":null,"end":null,"venue":null,"teamone":
        "hehe","teamtwo":"haha","s_name":"Soccer"}
```

What i need is for the start,end and venue to get the values from the schedules table. Something like this

```
{"schedule_response":[{"start":2016-11-30 00:00:00,"end":2016-12-01   
   00:00:00,"venue":aaaaaa,"teamone":"hehe","teamtwo":"haha","s_name":"Soccer"},
```

**Sample data of all tables**
[image]

Comment: Right join? People still use this? Either use `INNER JOIN` for only matches, or use your `RIGHT JOIN` when the right(in position) table is the leading table .

Comment: What is your main table? Sport or Schedule or Matches? Which table is the main table?

Comment: Right JOINs are vanishingly rare. Just sayin' ;-)

Comment: @viki888 main table is the schedule

Comment: @orange provide sample data, the result you are getting and the expected result.

Comment: @Viki888 provided the result i get and the expected result sir

Comment: @orange what about sample data? you have provided expected and the result which you are getting. But sample data is missing.

Comment: @Viki888 what you mean by sample data sir? like what will i input?

Comment: @orange sample data from each table.

Comment: @Viki888 added a photo sir

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query
 And please format your queries

Comment: INNER JOIN sport and matches then LEFT JOIN schedule

Comment: The value of schedule will be null because there is no relationship between matches.m_id and schedule.m_id

Comment: @Odin I still get null values in schedule

Comment: Matches.m_id says 150 and 151 while schedule.m_id says null and null. Try and replace the NULL and NULL in schedule.m_id to 150 and 151 then check your result.

Comment: yes @Odin i forgot to insert the m_id on schedule. Thank you very much for that one. I now get what i needed

Comment: Enjoy coding and don't forget to vote or should i make it a post ?- Orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INNER JOIN sport and matches then LEFT JOIN schedule

Matches.m_id says 150 and 151 while schedule.m_id says null and null.

Try and replace the NULL and NULL in schedule.m_id to 150 and 151 then check your result

Answer (score -1):

The same query which uses `left join` instead of `right join`.

```
Select * 
from `schedule ` as t1 
 left join `matches` as t2 
 left join `sport` as t3 
where t1.m_id = t2.m_id 
 and t2.s_id = t3.o_id
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax.